# How does a pushdown automaton know how to read a palindrome?

Tags: computation-theory, pushdown-automaton

For example, how does a PDA know how to read a palindrome in L = {a, b}*?

PDA that accepts palindromes over {a,b}* :

[image]

So, based on my drawing of the PDA:

How does it know when the first half of the string is on the final terminal (letter of the alphabet), and therefore knows to go from state 0 to state 1 (and furthermore knowing to "pop" letters from the stack backwards, hence creating the palindrome)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a *nondeterministic* pushdown automata. The answer to your question is that it *guesses* and may be assumed to guess correctly. Nondeterministic automata accept a string *w* if *any* path along which *w* might be processed results in *w*'s being accepted.

If we define acceptance as having an empty stack in an accepting state, then the only way something can be accepted by the above NPDA is if:

- it puts some stuff on the stack in state q0
- it eventually guesses that it needs to read the second half of the string
- it reads what it pushed onto the stack, but backwards, in q1

There are three "guesses" that the NPDA makes:

1. it guesses that the string is an even-length palindrome when it guesses e e/e, where e is used in place of lambda.
2. it guesses that the string is an odd-length palindrome with a in between the two halves when it guesses a e/e, where e is used in place of lambda
3. it guesses that the string is an odd-length palindrome with b in between the two halves when it guesses b e/e, where e is used in place of lambda

Each of the above three guesses is also guessing that the first half of the string, excluding a possible middle element, has been seen already.

This guess will eventually be true for any palindrome, and it won't be true for anything but a palindrome, so the NPDA accepts PAL.